# Why would VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates return no results?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Working on a Metro style app in C#.  I have a custom control which inherits from Grid.  MyGrid contains some other custom controls. I'm trying to do hit testing on those controls in the PointerReleased handler:

```
void MyGrid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(this);
    var hits = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(pt.Position, this);
    int breakhere = hits.Count();
}
```

After this code executes, hitCount is 0.  If I move the PointerReleased handler one control higher in the visual tree heirarchy then hitCount is correct the first time and 0 after that.  I set up a test project with similar XAML layout to try to reproduce the problem and it works correctly every time.  So I'm  not sure what bad thing I have done that is preventing VisualTreeHelper from working.  I'm not really sure how to proceed debugging this.  Any ideas what would cause this function to return no results?